# Clicking on a link in a Bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap js popovers to show an html list with links.  But I am having trouble grabbing the links when they are clicked with a jquery selector:

The element for the popover:

```
<span class="popoverSpan" data-style="listPopovers" data-html="true" data-container="body" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover" tabindex="0" data-original-title="" title="">Menu</span>

<div>
    <ul id="forPopover" class="dropdown-menu popover-content">
        <li id="List_3" class="subgroups">
            <a id="aInner">Students</a>
        </li>
        <li id="" class="subgroups">
            <a id="bInner">Teachers</a>   
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



$(".popoverSpan").popover({
        html: true,
        content: function () {

            return $('#forPopover').html();
        }
    });


 $('body').on('click', '.subgroups a', function (event) {
       alert('a');
    });
```

I have the popover html above and the JQuery and bootstrap code below it.  The alert('a') is intermittent.  Why is this the case and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Can you tell me what is it you are looking for... here is a fiddle i created http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/mfnevhon/

Comment: The above fiddle is shows what I mean. It doesn't work all the time: http://screencast.com/t/BzAW0tgaRDok

Answer (score 8):

It's a bit late for OP, but I just ran into this myself (I'm on Bootstrap v3.2). The problem is the `data-trigger="focus"`.

If you look at [the description in the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) `focus` is also described as "dismiss on next click", which it turns out includes clicks on the popover itself and even clicks on links in the popover. So there's a race between the click making bootstrap dismiss the popover and the click event reaching the link and actually open a new page.

Personally I think making `focus` dismiss on the next click anywhere **but** on the popover would be more intuitive.

Anyway, there are two solutions I can see. The first is to set the `data-trigger` to manual, then reimplement `focus` but don't dismiss if the click is on the popover.

The other is a bit more hacky, but if you add a delay, with `data-delay="500"` or preferably `.popover(delay: {show: 0, hide: 500})`, then the delay gives the click event time to open the page before the dismissal goes through. The latter only delays on close so since they'll be looking at a new page the delay isn't a problem if you don't want it. N.B. in theory you should also be able to do `data-delay="{show: 0, hide: 500}"` but I couldn't get that to work.

The second workaround is quick and easy, and the unwanted delay shouldn't be too big a deal, but be aware that there's always a chance of running into timing problems intermittently under certain conditions (faster/slower machine, diff browser, who knows?). So it could fail in CI or something. The higher you make the delay the smaller the chance that's a problem (e.g. I tried 50 and it virtually never worked for me) but then you've got a big delay to deal with.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice.  I was able to get the attribute to work by doing: `data-delay='{ "show": 0, "hide": 250 }'` but I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.7 so maybe this is just something they fixed in the meantime. Anyway, thanks for this.